# Django 1.9 updating model object makes a new object instance

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django 1.9 and noticed some strange behavior when working with the models. I know that the following code creates an object, saves it to the database, changes the field, then updates that same entry in the database:

```
cat = models.Cat(name="Bob")
cat.save()
cat.name = "Sally"
cat.save()
```

However, when I query all my objects using `cats = models.Cat.objects.all()` I find that rather than returning `["Sally"]` it actually returns `["Bob", "Sally"]`. Apparently `cat.save()` is creating a new element in the database rather than updating an existing one. I've worked with Django before, but never had this issue. One thing to note is that the `name` attribute is the primary key for the Cat model. Could this be why it's not updating, but creating a whole new entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the issue here is that your primary key is the `name` field. Django will do an update if the `pk` value exists in the database, and an insert if it doesn't. For example:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

cat = Cat(name='Bart')
cat.save()  # This creates a new object
print(cat.pk)
> '1'

cat.name = 'Sally'
cat.save()  # This updates the object, the pk will still be '1'
print(cat.pk)
> '1'

print(Cat.objects.all())
> [<Cat 'Sally'>]

fluffy = Cat(name='Fluffy')
fluffy.pk = 1
fluffy.save()
'''This will UPDATE the existing object, since an object
with that primary key already exists'''
print(Cat.objects.all())
> [<Cat 'Fluffy'>]

fluffy.pk = 2
fluffy.save()
'''This will CREATE a new object, since no object with
that primary key already exists'''

print(Cat.objects.all())
> [<Cat 'Fluffy'>, <Cat 'Fluffy'>]
```

If possible, I would recommend removing the `primary_key=True` attribute on the `name` field. If you want `name` to be unique, maybe just set `unique=True` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The primary key is what Django uses to determine whether to update or create an item. Usually, that's an opaque ID which you don't modify; but in your case, it's part of your data. When you modify the value, Django has no way of knowing that the object refers to an existing row in the database.

Don't do this; stick with autoincremented IDs that have no relation to your actual data.